# Installing Ubuntu on a Lenovo A740 (Touchscreen): (initramfs) Unable to find a Live Medium Containing a file system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I'm stuck in installing (any versions between 16.04 LTS - 17.04 tried) Ubuntu.
The machine (Lenovo 27" A7 Series) has as OS CentOS7 (minimal), want to obviously install Ubuntu on it.

#### What I did until now

- Created USB Stick (FAT32) with UNetbooting and Etcher (workaround on mentioned Ubuntu versions above)
- 1 USB Stick is a USB2.0 the other an USB3.0
- Running machine booting USB Stick
- Installation modes are coming up
- tried to install in different ways (try ubuntu, instal, OEM etc.)
- tried to update the Kernel from `3.10.0` up to `4.11.0`
- Ubuntu Installation Screen shows sometimes up (Language) than freezed

#### Result is still

- *(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file System*
  Screen freezes with a Flashing cursos at the end line.

If I'm running machine normally on CentOS can't access to command line (to at least work around the system) due I tried install a GNOME Desktop, because of the *frustration* that wasn't / isn't working.

#### Now

I'm stuck in a system that can't install a new OS and an OS I can't handle without terminal access.

Setting up BIOS isn't changing that much, just the initialisation to boot device can be managed.
Someone has some proper solutions for this issue, I would much appreciate to finally could at least run the installation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was "initramfs" message, so I'll limit myself to describe the solution for installing Ubuntu on a "Levovo A740" (which should workd on all machines).
I got a proper solution after testing around, wich is a simple unselect of some APIC's.

1. Create a bootable UBS Drive (be sure you create A FAT32)
   Grab your copy of [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) OR [Etcher](https://etcher.io/)
2. Install Ubuntu

Once you normally restart your system with insert Bootable UBS Stick you got the Ubuntu Installation Screen as this:[image]

**HOTFIX!!!**
 1. Press F6 and select with **SPACE BAR** the `noapic` and `nolapic`
 2. press **ESC** after you're made the selection on list
 3. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing" -> Machine will run like a VM.

You'll now on the main Ubuntu Desktop!
Select the Ubuntu Installation image you'll find on Desktop following the common installation procedure.

[image]

After you're installed Ubuntu system restarts and you'll get this screen:
[image]

Remove your USB device and let system Restart.
Congratulation you're running Ubuntu on your machine!

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Heres what I do to make sure things go right.

- Stick with usb 2.0 ONLY
- Find out which partitioning sheme GPT or MBR your current drive is in. this step can be skipped if the SSD/HHD you plan to install to has no partitions that you wish to keep.
- Create the USB key :

  - Simply [download this](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=17.04&architecture=amd64).
  - Format your USB 2.0 key to FAT32 using gparted.
  - (Still in Gparted) Right click on the visualised partition and select "manage flags" tick "boot" and apply.
  - Now simply mount the iso by double cliking it (this should open it's folder).
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
  - Go into the still-mounted folder of the formatted USB 2.0 key.
  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
  - Reboot and go into BIOS (make sure UEFI boot is enabled and) reorder boot priority so as to hav the USB (in UEFI mode first) save a restart.

Let's stop here for now tell me if this succeded but really from there everything else should be more or less intuitive.

Comment: First thanks for your fast reply. I should mention, I'm working on a MacBook Pro... so I won't be able to gparting the partition unless unsing Diskutil which works fine. After this step I can't rella understand what you mean where I have to select these folders. "managed Flags" and "boot" can't be selected anywhere! BTW. having same issue following (on Mac) your advice.

Comment: uhm not to contradict you but have you tried this : https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.21.0-1/gparted-live-0.21.0-1-i586.iso/download?use_mirror=kent?SetFreedomCookie

Comment: also on mac you can do this with fdisk : `fdisk /dev/sdd` replace "sdd" with corect device. then type `a` if there's one last step it should be `1` (because first partition) but other than that congrats you've added the "boot" flag to your usb key making it bootable!

Comment: thanks for your reply. gparted can't be run on my machine, or at least I don't know how to run an iso on my machine, due DiskImageMounter on mac is not opening the app you've provided form Sourceforge (no filesystem could be bound). It just get to complete it's own process on Terminal. Btw.. Trying with fdisk (more comfortable) and encountering same mentioned error of this thread. :(

Comment: fdisk fails to mark the usb key as bootable? did not did you continue by extreacting the iso I provided to the usb key and attempting to boot to it?

Comment: I was Trying your suggestion, the traditional one (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) and as well the manual one over terminal (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick). Unfortunately none of these are working. Still not able to find a filesystem.

Comment: well how about we agree these methods are not working for you (nor maybe anyone) and we should try my approach for argument's sake?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58648/discussion-between-gianni-and-tatsu).

Comment: I'm available now